# How to access an array outside if? I use ajax

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

I send data via ajax (1, 2, 3, 4) and try to write them in the 'pColors' array. The problem is I can not access the array.
I did the tests and confirmed that the data arrives at $ _POST but not recorded in the array.

```
$x = $getProductID;
$_SESSION['pColors'] = array();

if(isset($_POST['pColors'])) {  

   foreach($_POST['pColors'] as $colorKey => $RColors) {

      $_SESSION['pColors'][$x][$colorKey] = $RColors;   

    }
}
```

$x get product id I use them for key

Any ideas on what this is due to? Тhanks !

```
                $('.addToCart').click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url:""+realLink+"cart.php",
                        method:"POST",
                        data:{pColors:pColors},
                            success:function(data){
                               //alert(pColors);
                               //console.log(this.data);
                            }
                    });
                });
```

Comment: Why you use $_SESSION and not just a simple array to return in your ajax to be used on success? Also can you provide us with your ajax call as well?

Comment: How to get it back to ajax? Using ```success:function(data){ alert(data); }```  ?

Comment: return it if it's a function or print_r(); it . JS will pick it up if you print/echo results

Comment: `session_start()`? and do you return the array?

Comment: @dWinder 
Yes added immediately after opening the php tag

Comment: what is the output of print_r($_SESSION['pColors']); ?

Comment: @Declan Output: ``` Array
(
)```

Comment: Can we start at the beginning? What _exactly_ is contained in `$_POST['pColors']`. I doubt it is an array, and you don't test this with `is_array()`.

Comment: Can you show your AJAX data?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Hello! The content of $ _POST ['pColors'] is numbers 1 to 4.
There is something very interesting that happens but it does not work:
When I get the declaration of the array inside of if it gets the values ​​that are sent to $ _POST. But with a new spin, these values ​​are overwritten. ``` Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

) ```
I tested it with is_array (); and returned a confirmation that it is an array.

Comment: @balzacLeGeek data:{pColors:pColors} this or printed data if success ?

Comment: Where does the `Array([3] => Array([0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4))` come from? Is that from `print_r($_POST);`? Currently I am still unsure as to the _exact_ content of `$_POST['pColors']`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware 
Come from print_r ($ _ SESSION ['pColors']) but this data is only written to the array when it is inside if

Comment: I wasn't interested in the content of `$_SESSION['pColors']` at all. You say you have a problem accessing the `$_POST` array? Right?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware $_POST['pColors'] return nothing

Comment: You now contradict what you say in your question: "I did the tests and confirmed that the data arrives at $ _POST". So what is in `$_POST`?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware 
When data is retrieved through ajax they can hardly be read in php. There is an option to track in the console when it comes out. The console returns a confirmation that the data is sent, even showing what is sent to cart.php.
The other check I actually took into account is that when the array is declared in if it records the data successfully.

Comment: {pColors:pColors}, what is in pColors? How are you assigning the value to it?

Comment: @VipinKumarSoni https://github.com/eSportBG/colors/blob/master/code this is the code

Comment: var pColors = get_filter('pColor'); In console.log what is in pColors?

Comment: As I don't know what this "get_filter" function is doing?

Comment: @VipinKumarSoni I added the rest of the js code github.com/eSportBG/colors/blob/master/code

Answer (score 1):

So not sure how I didn't see this sooner, but your javascript variable for pColors is defined outside the function calling the ajax, there you are sending empty data.

I modified your script to the following:

```
<script>
filter_data();

function filter_data() {

    var action = 'fetch_data';


    $('.addToCart').click(function(){

        var pColors = document.getElementById("pColors").value
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://samplesite/devsite/ajax.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{ pColors : pColors },
                success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
}
        });
    });

}
    </script>
```

Tested on my development server and it outputs the following:

```
Array
(
    [pColors] => 1,2,3,4
)
```

Edit:

Also needed to change the ajax php file to the following:

```
$x = $getProductID;
$_SESSION['pColors'] = array();



    if(isset($_POST['pColors'])) {  
        foreach($_POST as $colorKey => $value) {
            if ($colorKey == 'pColors') { 


            $_SESSION['pColors'][$colorKey] = $value;
        }
        }

    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_SESSION['pColors']);
    echo '</pre>';
```

You'll notice the foreach is now running on the $_POST method itself with an if statement to then check it's the correct key.

I've now added:

```
$colorFolder = "Placeholder Folder";

$getColorTitle = array("uniqueID" => "2");

$rowColors = array("image" => "Placeholder Image");


echo '
                                  <li>
                                  <input type="hidden" class="getColorID" id="'.$getColorTitle['uniqueID'].'" />
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="pColors" class="css-checkbox pColor" value="'.$getColorTitle['uniqueID'].'" id="cb-'.$getColorTitle['uniqueID'].'"/>
                                    <label for="cb-'.$getColorTitle['uniqueID'].'"><img src="'.$colorFolder.''.$rowColors['image'].'" height="50px" />
                                <div class="colorsC">
                                <input type="hidden" value="0" style="width: 45px;" class="qtyC" />
                                    <input type="button" value="0" style="width: 45px;" class="qtyC addToCart" />
                                </div>
                                    </label>
                                  </li>';

                                  ?>
```

which outputs:

```
test.php:117 <pre>Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [pColors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )

        )

)
</pre>
```

Which is the correct ID

--- cart.php ----

```
<?php


$_SESSION['pID'] = "9";

$_SESSION['pQua'] = "20";


if(isset($_SESSION['pID']) && isset($_SESSION['pQua'])) {
    foreach($_SESSION as $getProductID => $valueTwo) {
        if ($getProductID == "pID")   {
        $x = $getProductID;
        $_SESSION['pColors'] = array();

if(isset($_POST['pColors'])) {
    foreach($_POST as $colorKey => $value) {
        if ($colorKey == 'pColors') { 
            $_SESSION['pColors'][$x][$colorKey] = $value;
        }
    }
}

    }
}
}

            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($_SESSION['pColors']);
            echo '</pre>';


?>
```

-- product.php ---

```
<?php

include_once 'header.php';

$colorFolder = "Placeholder Folder";

$getColorTitle = array("uniqueID" => "2");

$rowColors = array("image" => "Placeholder Image");


echo '
                                  <li>
                                  <input type="hidden" class="getColorID" id="'.$getColorTitle['uniqueID'].'" />
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="pColors" class="css-checkbox pColor" value="'.$getColorTitle['uniqueID'].'" id="cb-'.$getColorTitle['uniqueID'].'"/>
                                    <label for="cb-'.$getColorTitle['uniqueID'].'"><img src="'.$colorFolder.''.$rowColors['image'].'" height="50px" />
                                <div class="colorsC">
                                <input type="hidden" value="0" style="width: 45px;" class="qtyC" />
                                    <input type="button" value="0" style="width: 45px;" class="qtyC addToCart" />
                                </div>
                                    </label>
                                  </li>';

                                  ?>
```

--- ajaxCart.js ---

```
<script>filter_data();

function filter_data() {

    $('.addToCart').click(function(){

        var pColors = get_filter('pColor');

        $.ajax({
            url:"http://samplesite/devsite/ajax2.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{ pColors : pColors },
                success:function(data){
                   //alert(pColors);
                   console.log(data);
                }
        });
    });

}

function get_filter(class_name) {
    var filter = [];
    $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
        filter.push($(this).val());
    });

    if($('.'+class_name+'').is(':checked')){
        $('.colorsC').find('input:hidden').each(function() {
           $("<input type='text' />").attr({ style: 'width: 45px;', value: this.value }).insertBefore(this);
        }).remove();                    
    } else {
        $('.colorsC').find('input:text').each(function() {
           $("<input type='hidden' />").attr({ style: 'width: 45px;', value: '0' }).insertBefore(this);
        }).remove();
    }

    return filter;
}

$('.css-checkbox').click(function(){
    filter_data();
   });

$('.addToCart').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    productID = $(this).attr('id');
    productQuantity = $('#productID'+productID+'').val();

    $.post('http://samplesite/devsite/ajaxAddProduct.php', {
        pID: productID,
        pQua: productQuantity,
    }, function(response){
        $('#successID'+productID+'').show('slow');
    });
    alert('Успешно добавихте продукта в количката');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#successID'+productID+'').hide('slow');

    }, 1000);

    return false;
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you ! I tried the code just as you described it, but for some reason I get an empty array.

Comment: I made a call for var pColors = document.getElementById("pColors").value in my code, you might want to make sure that isn't in yours, needs changing back to var pColors = get_filter('pColor');

Comment: Yes, I changed it right away as I send the values ​​when a color is highlighted.
... I begin to think it has something to do with the rest of the code. 
I posted the whole js https://github.com/eSportBG/colors/blob/master/code

Comment: This is the response I get using your filter and a checkbox rather than the input and value from document id:test.php:116 <pre>Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [pColors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => on
                )

        )

)
</pre>

Comment: lol.. How can I make it send correct data when marking a color?

Comment: Well, what are these variables equal too? value="'.$getColorTitle['uniqueID'].'" id="cb-'.$getColorTitle['uniqueID'].'"

Comment: console return: pColors%5B%5D=1&pColors%5B%5D=2&pColors%5B%5D=3&pColors%5B%5D=4

Comment: @BaiHui I've edited by answer check the bottom, the code is running and outputting the correct unique ID, what is yours doing?

Comment: I see two id here ``` <input type="checkbox" name="pColors" class="css-checkbox pColor" id="pColors" value="'.$getColorTitle['uniqueID'].'" id="cb-'.$getColorTitle['uniqueID'].'"/>  ```

Comment: Correct, that's left over from the previous testing, I've removed it and still get the same output. Where are you still having issues?

Comment: I'm not sure. But there is something very interesting ... When I declare the array inside of if I get the values ​​and they are recorded in the array, but when the next request is rewritten

Comment: I have a few questions: Where do you declare session_start (); ? Is the probability that the problem is in the method by which I pick the selected color itself as it sends to the filter_data () function? and it is called after a click.

Comment: Ok so, you declare the session start before assign values or try to match against $_SESSIONS. The data is definitely being sent at this point, you're just not getting a response.

Comment: checking your entire code, I can see you have done an if statement here: if(isset($_SESSION['pID']) AND isset($_SESSION['pQua'])) { the AND needs to be && also you are using a foreach on the session key itself here: if(isset($_SESSION['pID']) && isset($_SESSION['pQua'])) {

Comment: try changing the foreach to :     foreach($_SESSION as $getProductID => $value) { and add an if statement of if ($getProductID == 'pID') {

Comment: The code is working on my end, without further information there is really nothing I can do.

Comment: @baiHui I've added the entire edited version of your code to my answer, please go through and look for little mistakes, please don't just copy and paste it, that won't help you learn where you went wrong.

Comment: Hello ! Thank you ! 
I'm starting to think that the problem is with me, because it's a little unbelievable for me to be with you. I'm obviously messing up somewhere. I put the entire source code of the files. Thanks !